# Load a view on ember select change?

Tags: ember.js

How can you load a view or template content when ember select element changes?

I'm barely new to ember, this might be quite easy but I've been struggling too much already for this simple task. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show your codes ?

Comment: providing a fiddle may help you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on @intuitivepixel's answer, here is how to dynamically load a template based on select change.

```
//EMBER APP TEMPLATE
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
      return [
          {name: 'Kris', template: 'kris'},
          {name: 'Luke', template: 'luke'},
          {name: 'Alex', template: 'alex'}
      ];
  }
});

App.EmbeddedView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: Ember.computed.alias('controller.selected'),
  templateNameDidChange: function() {
    this.rerender();
  }.observes('templateName')
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h4>Load a view on ember select change?</h4>
  {{view Ember.Select 
         contentBinding="this" 
         optionValuePath="content.template" 
         optionLabelPath="content.name" 
         valueBinding="selected" 
         prompt="Please select a name"
  }}
  <hr/>
  {{view App.EmbeddedView}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="luke">
  THE LUKE TEMPLATE
</script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="alex">
  THE ALEX TEMPLATE
</script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="kris">
  THE KRIS TEMPLATE
</script>
```

This example will switch between the luke/alex/chris templates depending on the select box.

See this jsbin for a live example: http://jsbin.com/uzekop/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

Although you should post some code of what you have tried, [this example](http://jsbin.com/ebigeb/3/edit) might help you get started so you can improve your question.

See [here](http://jsbin.com/ebigeb/3/edit) for an example on how you could change a button label depending on the selected value of a select box.

Hope it helps.